# Netbeans PHP Code Folding fromatting

Tags: php, netbeans, format, folding

I use the  tag in Netbeans to fold custom segments of code to structure my doc a bit. The functionality of it is great, BUT everytime I insert the  tag, the code inside this tag becomes formatted in a way that I don't like, e.g:

this is how I write it:

```
if(foo==bar)
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //do anything
}
```

After inserting the editor-fold this piece of code reads:

```
if(foo==bar)     {
   //do something
}      else      {
   //do anything
}
```

Maybe this is how 'professional coders format their if-statements, but I like the upper better, I am familiar with it. Is there a possiblity to prevent netbeans to format my code when inserting a editor-fold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting

You can set things the way you like there.

Comment: on netbeans 7.1.1 this option is not present